# Erro na declaração de variável no loop

Tags: c, loop, gcc, for

Fiz o seguinte comando:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++) {etc
}
```

Então deu o seguinte erro quando fui compilar:

```
game.c:11:2: error: "for" loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++) {
/\ //essa seta apontando pro "f"
game.c:11:2: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

O que fazer?

Comment: Como a própria mensagem de erro disse, use a opção `-std=c99` ou `-std=gnu99` ao chamar o compilador (ou mova o `int i` pra fora do loop). Aparentemente você não pode declarar uma variável dentro de um `for` na versão do C que você está usando (isso pode a partir do C99).

Comment: Para referência, a diferença entre usar `c99` e `gnu99` é que esse segundo permite extensões da GNU (i.e. específicas do gcc), enquanto o primeiro segue mais estritamente a especificação. Então, se você quiser código **portável** (que possa ser compilado por outros tipos de compilador C), use o primeiro, se quer/precisa de alguma extensão específica, use o segundo.

Answer (score 7):

Na versão do C que está utilizando não é permitido criar uma variável dentro de um comando `for`

Experimente separar as instruções em:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++){ etc... }
```

Answer (score 6):

Deve fazer o que a mensagem está dizendo, colocar `-std=c99` na linha de comando quando for compilar.

Se você não consegue interpretar uma simples mensagem de erro que diz o que deve fazer, você terá enormes dificuldades para programar, isto ocorre o tempo todo. Especialmente em C tem erros bem cabeludos. Por isto preste atenção no que o compilador te diz, ele pode não conseguir resolver pra você, mas ele diz coisas importantes. Em cosias simples assim é só seguir o que ele diz na mensagem de erro.

Ou pode fazer o que diz as outras respostas mas esta é uma técnica arcaica que deve ser evitada se não existir um motivo para usá-la.

Comment: comecei hoje, to pegando as manhas ainda... =D

Comment: A melhor dica que eu estou te dando é prestar muita atenção no que o compilador te diz, ele sabe o que está errado e dá informações importantes e corretas do que deve fazer. Claro que alguns cabe interpretação, mas essa é bem simples.

Comment: beleza, me dedicarei mais!

Answer (score 5):

Coloque a declaração do inteiro fora do *loop*:

```
int i;
for(i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++) { ... }
```

Possivelmente esta versão do compilador é bem antiga, ou está definida [para a versão C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

Uma outra solução que você pode tentar fazer é compilar da seguinte forma:

```
$ gcc -g game.c -std=c99
```

Ou ainda:

```
$ gcc -g game.c -std=gnu99
```